# Does Android save videos from Instagram live in the cache?

Tags: video, cache, instagram

I hosted an instagram live interview yesterday and when it came to saving it to post to IGTV there was an error. I believe it was either due to a network error or that there may not have been enough space on my phone to save or process the video (I have 3.1 GB available, it was a 57 min live video.)

[image: screenshot of error message]
[image: preview of IG live post to IGTV]

Eventually after editing the title and text multiple times thinking it was a character limit or doesn't like punctuation etc, as well as switching off flight mode and switching on data in case it was the network, I had to abandon the video. It is not saved in my stories or my archive on Instagram or anywhere on IGTV.

I've looked in the Android files on my Samsung S8 under com.instagram, cache and videos, and in movies and downloads, but cannot find it. Would it be saved somewhere on my phone?

Would the reason for the error be insufficient storage space or more likely network error?

Answer (score 0):

You're only able to save a live video right after you've ended it. Only you will see the option to save your live video. So, I doubt it's cached somewhere...